# Room Database Not Persisting Data

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, mvvm, android-room

I have setup a room database in a Kotlin, Jetpack-compose, MVVM app and have been using the room database to save and access data in view models and instrumentation testing. All seems to work perfectly good and well. However, whenever I rerun the application the data that was previously in the room database stored in memory was not written to the disk (I believe this since I used Android Studio's Device File Explorer to monitor the values written in the .db file) and therefore doesn't actually save. It looks like the db-shm file and db-wal files get updated just as frequently as the in app database. However, the .db file itself is only created and then never touched by the app again until it eventually decides to create another one.

I have looked at many suggestions as possible about this online, and it seems like everywhere it is just supposed to be handled automatically, yet this isn't happening. I have commented out "fallbackToDestructiveMigration", verified that the file I am looking at is the same name of the file reference in app, commented out ".createFromAsset", closed the database on MainActivity Destroy, opened the database on app open. The database works completely as expected in app just not across restarts. NOTE: I AM NOT USING THE IN MEMORY DATABASE. Not sure where to go from here.

Here is the source code for the database.

```
@Database(entities = [BaseUser::class, CommonInfo::class, BaseFriend::class], version = 4, exportSchema = false)
abstract class MyDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun commonInfoDao(): CommonInfoDao
    abstract fun userDao(): UserDao
    abstract fun friendDao(): FriendDao


    companion object {
        // Singleton prevents multiple
        // instances of database opening at the
        // same time.
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: MyDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context): MyDatabase {


            // if the INSTANCE is not null, then return it,
            // if it is, then create the database
            return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    MyDatabase::class.java,
                    "my_database.db"
                )//.fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                 //.createFromAsset("my_database.db")
                    .build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                // return instance
                instance
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not related to your question, but there's an error in the Room with a View tutorial where it shows you how to create a singleton instance, and you have copied that error. If two threads call `getDatabase` at the same time, you can end up with two instances of your database. Inside the synchronized block, you need to check again if `INSTANCE` is null, and if it's not null, return it instead of creating the new instance.

Comment: Is it possible your run configuration in Android Studio is set to wipe data or reinstall each time you re-run the app?

Comment: I can try the first suggestion to see if that works. As far as the run configuration is concerned, I don't know if it is (although I suspect it isn't enabled since sharedPrefs saves fine) if I install the apk on the device and then run it locally on the device completely independent of studio, this same problem happens so it's likely not that one.

Answer (score -2):

Updated everything within the module gradle (kotlin, gradle plugin, room etc.), switched to ksp instead of kapt and made sure to close the database and set the INSTANCE var to null on the onDestroy callback of the Main Activity. This has fixed the issues!